# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError using ui4j in Linux Mint

Tags: java, ubuntu, webkit, ui4j

I am getting the following exception when running my application in Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon 64-bit but do not get an error with the code in Windows. ElementImpl looks to belong to jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar and I've tried setting that with java.library.path but I think the issue has more to do with the code not finding the correct native library to carry out the getOuterHTMLImpl code? I've installed libwebkitgtk also but no luck.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.webkit.dom.ElementImpl.getOuterHTMLImpl(J)Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.sun.webkit.dom.ElementImpl.getOuterHTMLImpl(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webkit.dom.ElementImpl.getOuterHTML(ElementImpl.java:142)
    at com.ui4j.webkit.dom.WebKitElement.getOuterHTML(WebKitElement.java:776)
    at com.ui4j.webkit.dom.WebKitElement$ByteBuddy$Y2TpKYyB.getOuterHTML$accessor$jCxpanOa(Unknown Source)
    at com.ui4j.webkit.dom.WebKitElement$ByteBuddy$Y2TpKYyB$auxiliary$ZZL1EYza.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.ui4j.webkit.proxy.WebKitProxy$CallableExecutor.run(WebKitProxy.java:46)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What is your Java version?

Comment: oracle java version "1.8.0_131"

Answer (score 0):

Just use open jdk, it worked for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem on some linux machines. Only working solution I've found so far is using JavaScript execution:

```
Object outerHTML = page.executeScript("document.body.outerHTML;");
```